# Missing ':' after AES encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, character, aes

I am writing a software program that needs to encrypt and save a URL to a text file, and decrypt it later.  I'm using a simple AES encryption/decryption call:

```
private string EncryptString(string TargetString, string EncryptionKey)
    {
        var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TargetString);
        var encrypted = getAes(EncryptionKey).CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    private string DecryptString(string TargetString, string EncryptionKey)
    {
        var b = Convert.FromBase64String(TargetString);
        var decrypted = getAes(EncryptionKey).CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(b, 0, b.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
    }

    private Aes getAes(string EncryptionKey)
    {
        var keyBytes = new byte[16];
        var skeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);
        Array.Copy(skeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, skeyBytes.Length));

        Aes aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.Key = keyBytes;
        aes.IV = keyBytes;

        return aes;
    }
```

Everything appears to work fine with one exception: I loose the ':' character in https://...

Here is what I encrypt and save:

[image]

...and when I reload and decrypt I get:

[image]

The ':' is gone.  When I debug I see the ':' going into the encryption method to be saved, but when I reload the text file and decrypt, the ':' is gone.  Everything else is as I expect.

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

c# - .Net 5

Thanks.

-Joe

Comment: Can you narrow down the possibilities by simply encrypting and decrypting without base64 encoding the bytestream?

Comment: It seems highly doubtful the shown code can cause the behavior. Is it reproducible locally in LINQPad (outside of any other code context)?

Comment: Agreed. "Removing" the colon would entirely screw up the decryption. It is more likely that something else is removing the colon post-decryption.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!  Additional debugging allowed me to see that it was reading it back out of the file and decrypting it.  I had a "Replace" command later in the code to pull out some formatting data that pulled out the ':'.  Thanks for pointing me AWAY from the encryption or I'd still be looking there.  #TunnelVision  Thanks.